# .env.* files are not picking up in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app, react-scripts

in my reactjs app, which has been created with `creat-react-app`, I've created these files

- .env
- .env.developmnet
- .env.development.local

which contains `REACT_APP_END_POINT=localhost:3001`

the problem is when I run `npm start` the `process.env.REACT_APP_END_POINT` is `undefined`, but if I run the command like `REACT_APP_END_POINT=localhost:3001 npm start`, everything is fine.
here is the versions for related packages:

- "react": "^16.13.1"
- "react-scripts": "3.4.1"

Comment: Where are your `.env` place. In my current project the `.env` file place as the same level with `src` and 'package.json'. let's check that.

Comment: @Jaylers, ooops!!! what a silly mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure your `.env` place as the same level with `src` and 'package.json'